# ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleCookie' error

Tags: python, django

I tried to runserver with the manage.py but I get this error.
I am a newbie in django framework. I am following tutsplus tutorial for news aggregator.

```
bash -cl "/Users/Spandan/PycharmProjects/newsproject/venv/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py runserver /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/Spandan/PycharmProjects/newsproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
        autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
      File "/Users/Spandan/PycharmProjects/newsproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/Spandan/PycharmProjects/newsproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 16, in setup
        from django.urls import set_script_prefix
      File "/Users/Spandan/PycharmProjects/newsproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .base import (
      File "/Users/Spandan/PycharmProjects/newsproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .exceptions import NoReverseMatch, Resolver404
      File "/Users/Spandan/PycharmProjects/newsproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/exceptions.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.http import Http404
      File "/Users/Spandan/PycharmProjects/newsproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.http.cookie import SimpleCookie, parse_cookie
      File "/Users/Spandan/PycharmProjects/newsproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/http/cookie.py", line 2, in <module>
        from http import cookies
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.http.cookie import SimpleCookie, parse_cookie
    ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleCookie'
```

Comment: What's the version of `python` and `django` are you using?

Comment: please upload your requirements `pip freeze`

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.5 and Django 2.0.6 @nandal

Comment: @seuling Since I have installed Python 3.6.5, I used pip3 instead. 
Django==2.0.6
pytz==2018.4